# Identify this plant and suggestions for how to propagate it?

Tags: houseplants, propagation

*(Sorry for the less than clear photo)*

A co-worker was just given this great plant and I want one!

Leaves are green with spots on top and a bright burgundy underneath. The leaf stems are very thin which make me doubt that I can just clip a few and root them in water – but what do I know!?

Any information on what type of plant this is and how to propagate it will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Calathea lancifolia (rattlesnake plant) to me. When I propagated one, I did it by separation — taking it out of the pot and splitting it into multiple plants. New leaves come up from the roots, so the plant is easily divided this way. Good luck!

Comment: that's it: https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/rattlesnake-plant.html  - thanks!